# Why is potential energy at infinity zero when force at infinity is zero?

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, conventions

In case of electrostatics and electrodynamics, we can derive that force and potential energy at infinity is zero. However if we only know force at infinity is zero, then how can we derive from this fact that potential energy at infinite is also zero?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326797/

Comment: I suggest you read about [torsors](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electrostatic potential is zero at infinity because we *define* it that way; this result is not 'derived' from anything else. You can add any arbitrary constant to the potential, if you find it convenient, and it will be equally valid - but it will no longer be zero at infinity. The only reason we choose it to be zero at infinity is because it's convenient - nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Do you mean adding an arbitrary constant over the whole potential energy field?

Comment: @Joe Exactly that.

Comment: If we take that constant as zero, then why is it necessary that potential energy at infinity to be zero ?

Comment: **It is not necessary. It is a convention.** If you're given a function and all you know is that it is a potential (i.e. that $-\nabla\varphi = \mathbf E$) then there is no way to even define that constant. The question is essentially meaningless.

Comment: Do you mean even if the arbitrary constant is zero, then also we can (define) non-zero potential energy at infinity?

Comment: @Joe To the extent that that "arbitrary constant" can even be defined, then if it will make you happy, yes. To emphasize, though: the value of the potential at infinity has absolutely zero meaning in physical terms; it is entirely a metal and theoretical construct and it can be changed to whatever you want at the stroke of a pen. It's not worth spilling any more ink on it and I will stop doing so now.

Comment: @Joe To put it a different way, electrical potential is like altitude. We normally measure altitude from sea level, but it is perfectly fine to measure from the nearest bit of ground or from the center of the Earth. An airplane pilot does not care about sea level altitude if he's about to hit a mountain. Defining the electrical potential to be zero at infinity is mathematically convenient. When calculating physical effects, only differences in potential matter ($\vec{E} = -\nabla V$), so the absolute value of the potential is not important.

Answer (score 0):

If two objects are separated by infinity, then they cannot interact, because electromagnetic force will never reach opposite side, thus potential energy is zero, even if electromagnetic force is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter. what matters is the difference of potential energy, you can assume an arbitrary constant but it will cancel out when we take their difference 
Let at point $A$ potential energy be $Ua+P$ and at point $B$ potential energy be $Ub+P$. Now their difference will be simply $Ua-Ub$

Answer (score 0):

look at it this way , we have defined potential difference as the work done per unit charge.

work done can or can not be path dependent

suppose point A is a point near you and a point B is at a infinite distance from A
point B is at r= infinite distance from A

potential varies 1/r  so for r=infinite
1/r turns zero

potential at B some= constant * 1/r  = 0 only