# Follow up question to "Why is the Earth's potential taken to be zero?"

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage

I am questioning the validity of the problem posed in [Why is Earth's potential taken to be zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/720386/why-is-earths-potential-taken-to-be-zero).

The problem is stated as:

> "There are two thin concentric conducting shells of radius  and  (<), and the inner shell is given a charge  on its outer surface (charge induction will take place on outer shell) and also the outer shell is now earthed. Find the final charges on the shells".

Now, the answer posted by the user to this question implies that there is an induced surface charge density on both sides of the outer shell. However, to my understanding shell implies infinitesimally thin, allowing only a single surface charge density. I am used to seeing a conductor in the shape of a shell with a certain thickness holding an interior surface charge density and an exterior surface charge density.

I understand that there can be a normal surface dipole density on a surface. But, this would create a discontinuity in the potential at the surface of the shell (c.f. Jackson), which I do not think the problem stated by the user intends to ask about.

So, can a shell conductor hold separate surface charge density on both sides?

I feel like the problem is just not posed well.

Comment: Can you point to where in the answer you link to, there is a surface charge density on both sides of the outer shell? I think this problem can be solved with a single surface charge density on the inner shell, and one on the outer shell, without distinguishing the outer and inner sides of each shell. Admittedly, strictly speaking the problem statement probably did not need to specify "on the outer surface [of the inner shell]", but I think they probably had in mind a shell with finite but small thickness.

Comment: @Andrew This is what I was thinking as well (it is solvable with using a single surface charge density). Here's part of the answer provided by the user: "@jensenpaull here's the solution by my proffesor. firstly, charge -q is induced on inner surface of outer shell, and +q on outer surface of outer shell. Also assume charge q' comes from earth to outer's shell's outer surface. Now set the outer shell's potential as zero:" In particular, the solution mentions "outer's shell's outer surface".

Comment: I think the teacher's solution applies to the case where the shells are thin but not infinitesimally thin, so they have an inner and outer surface. For the infintesimal case, you would just add the charge densities, so the inner shell has charge $q$ and the outer shell has charge $q-q+q'=q-q-q=-q$.