# Better understanding of the definition of Gravitational Potential as the improper integral $\frac{1}{m}\int^x _{\infty}G\frac{Mm}{x^2}dx$

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, definition, conventions, integration

According to Wikipedia "The gravitational potential $V$ at a distance $x$ from a point mass of mass $M$ can be defined as the work $W$ that needs to be done by an external agent to bring a unit mass in from infinity to that point: $$V(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{m}\int^x _{\infty} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{x} = \frac{1}{m}\int^x _{\infty}G\frac{Mm}{x^2}dx$$

where $G$ is the gravitational constant, and $\vec{F}$ is the gravitational force."

---

**Question 1**: What is the meaning of "from infinity" here? We could integrate "from infinity" in a variety of ways, yet it seems we must integrate in the direction *away* from the point mass in question, right? Since otherwise we would get a different integral.

**Question 2**: How is the Gravitational Potential defined when there are multiple point masses in space?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365566/2451

Answer (score 0):

**Question (1):**

"Infinity" here refers to a distance that is at an infinite radial distance away from the source mass $M$. Essentially at $x = \infty$.

Note that this defintion is **incomplete**. The  definite integral you have written is equal to the gravitational potential *difference* between the two points (one at a radial distance $x$ and the other at a radial distance of $\infty$). However, it is usually a convention to assign a gravitational potential of zero to points that are at an infinte radial distance away from the source mass $M$, so the difference reduces to the gravitatonal potential of the point at a radial distance $x$ from the source mass.

**Question (2):**

The potential associated with a distribution of point masses at a point is the scalar *sum* of the individual potentials  at that point due to the masses constituting the system. This is often called the superposition of gravitational potential.

It is: $$V(x) = -\sum_{i = 1}^{n} G \frac{m_i}{|x-x_i|}$$
for a system of n-particles having masses $m_1, m_2, ..., m_n$ at distances $x_1, x_2...,x_n$ from the origin respectively at a point which is at a distance $x$ from the origin. This, of course also takes into consideration that the potential at $x = \infty$ is zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If what I wrote is the gravitational potential difference between two points, what is the definition of the gravitational potential at a single point? Will it not have the same definition?

Comment: Here's the deal: Potential and potential energy as such are _physically meaningless_. It is only the change in these quantities that is physically meaningful. It follows that there is no single valued definition for potential at a point, but it can be made if you assign a particular value of potential to a fixed point and then calculate all potentials with respect to that particular point. As I said, the most commonly chosen point is $x = \infty$ and it is assigned $V = U_g = 0$.

Comment: For more details you can see this Phys.SE post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19055/is-there-really-no-meaning-in-potential-energy-and-potential