# Why is closeness assorted with high potential energy and actually not being far away?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, potential-energy, thought-experiment

I know that, technically, given the standard convention $U=0$ at $r=\infty$ would imply that if $r$ is large, then $U$ would be small, hence justifying that close objects to a potential energy source would have high potential energy, but here's what I wonder:

Let's suppose a particle is in the electric field of another, where the particles have opposing charges, in two scenarios: one where it is just barely close enough to start hurdling towards it at some point $D$, and one where it is just a centimeter from it, let's label as point $A$. It is apparently factual that the closer particle will have higher potential energy, but I would argue (albeit incorrectly) that the farther particle will have higher potential energy. It is slowly hurdling towards the other particle, gaining kinetic energy, and *then* will be, at some point, a centimeter away from the other particle, like in the first scenario. However, it will have much more kinetic energy when starting to acquire kinetic energy from a very far distance away than the energy $K_{close}$ the centimeter-away particle obtains.

In my view, high potential energy implies the ability to acquire a high amount of kinetic energy if it is able to convert to kinetic. This is perhaps a bad definition, and thus the source of my confusion; and as such an answer explaining why my definition is poor would help me to understand it better. However, this then leads me to assume, that the farther away particle's kinetic energy until $r=0$ from the potential energy source would be:

$$K = K_{D \to A} + K_{A \to r=0}$$

While the initial position $A$ particle's kinetic energy when $r=0$ would be:

$$K = K_{A \to r=0}$$

And as such, I would argue that the farther away particle's $PE$ would be larger than the close one.

Comment: You're assuming $U$ is positive. In electromagnetic situations, $U$ is negative, so $U=0$ actually _does_ represent the maximum value.

Comment: Fair enough, but doesn’t answer my question.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326797/why-is-the-work-done-on-a-charge-calculated-from-infinity

Comment: @sangstar But it does. When you place particles farther away from each other, their potential energy becomes less negative (therefore, higher). The statement "the closer particle will have higher potential energy" is wrong.

Comment: @probably_someone Oh? Excuse me for sounding presumptuous then. Does that also apply to gravitation? It seems to confuse me due to the fact that at $r= /infty$ $U=0$ which would imply things quite far away would have a small potential energy

Comment: @sangstar This is indeed also true for gravity. Gravitational potential is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add this as a comment but apparently i do not have enough reputation for that.

Imagine you have a Particle with charge e at the origin, thus creating a Potential of
$$V(r) = \frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r}$$
for a second Particle of charge $-e$. This potential decreases to negative infinity at $r= 0$. Therefore the Potential Energy for a particle further away from this one is actually $\textit{higher}$ than when it is closer. Using the Points you defined in your question the Potential Energy of a Particle at D is higher than that of a particle at A. This stems from the fact that the Potential is negative for two oppositely charged particles and not positive.

Comment: GAH! $-\infty < 0$! So, my intuition is correct then?

Comment: So $U=0$ does *not* imply the object can't wrack up a ton of kinetic energy the longer it spends in a force field?

Comment: @sangstar you are right it does not. You will often be confronted with negative Potential Energy. But all this means is that the Energy of the composite System is lower than that of the two separate systems.