# What would happen if total energy of electron in bohr's orbit were positive?

Tags: atomic-physics

I have read somewhere that if electron had positive total energy in orbit it would not follow a closed orbit.
why is that so?

Comment: Because it would not be bound.

Comment: This can be done by replacing the electron with a positron.

Comment: It is worth looking at the notion of total energy in Newtonian orbits. [The conventional choice for describing the potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326797/why-is-the-work-done-on-a-charge-calculated-from-infinity) has the same form for the Coulomb force and universal gravitation.

Answer (score 1):

***If the electron had a positive energy, it would mean that the electron would no longer be bound to the nucleus.***

*Why does the electron have negative energy?*

This is because the electron has lost some energy and thus has been successfully attracted by the nucleus. Energy is released which implies that it is negative.

Positive energy with respect to the nucleus would mean that the electron is free since it hasn't lost any energy. This would ultimately mean that the electrons would no longer be revolving in the orbits and they would moving freely in the space.